Using text file as data input in Requests
I'm having trouble when I try to use a text file as data input in a Python request.
I have successfully used the particular code in another project but when I try to use it in the current one is impossible to format the text file data in such a way that is acceptable by the site.
The data for a single request looks  like  this data = {'Uid': '0587848'}. When I try to use a text file with many uids it gives an error that I need to give the uid.
What I suspect is that I am formatting the text file wrong. I have tried to format with quotes (single and double), no quotes, and everything in between. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
The full request is this:
import requests
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import sys

cookies = {
    'cookiesession1': '123456789992ECC739C98A4B01',
    'cookieconsent_status_UNCATEGORIZED': 'DISMISS',
    'cookieconsent_status_ESSENTIAL': 'DISMISS',
    'cookieconsent_status_PERSONALIZATION': 'DISMISS',
    'cookieconsent_status_ANALYTICS': 'DISMISS',
    'cookieconsent_status_MARKETING': 'DISMISS',
    'ROUTEID': '.31',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'po24rxtq4orb1t5bnjq1rhu4',
    '.ASPXAUTH': '9DE8AA8A8173A5F672CE5B36727992E9B9E92F89253C5C968B508B68ABDA59370FD4894548C3CBF84C55606E0199BAC8AFC19C3636A1E6A86960C285100870D0F0C0A38BD1F1C5333C016126DC323F213005A9AE5447542AB6C1F3E1167AD3FE642B04C4AF0CD955806E144C50E84100C335F497ED6B2C776305EC1C742443D42C97ECE681D986A764E2D2D6E470066621F39416',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'el-GR,el;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://thesite1234.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://thesite1234.com/Professionals/Inquiry/Main/SearchByPerson',
    # 'Cookie': 'cookiesession1=678A3E46CB3D57CE92ECC739C98A4B01; cookieconsent_status_UNCATEGORIZED=DISMISS; cookieconsent_status_ESSENTIAL=DISMISS; cookieconsent_status_PERSONALIZATION=DISMISS; cookieconsent_status_ANALYTICS=DISMISS; cookieconsent_status_MARKETING=DISMISS; ROUTEID=.31; ASP.NET_SessionId=po24rxtq4orb1t5bnjq1rhu4; .ASPXAUTH=9DE8AA8A8173A5F6C8AFC19C3636A1E6A86960C285100870D0F0C0A38BD1F1C5333C066621F39416',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
print("Current date & time : ", current_datetime)

str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)
with open(str_current_datetime+'.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('a.txt') as fp:
        for line in fp:  
            ull=requests.post('https://thesite1234.com/Professionals/Inquiry/Main/FetchPerson',cookies=cookies,headers=headers,data=line,)
            print(ull.text,file=outfile)
            print(ull.text)


(1) Fix the indentation of the shown code.

(2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

What does a line of the text file look like, because the payload (data) in the post request should be formatted as a dictionary (which would mean that Uid is a key and the value would be the corresponding Uid in your text file)

I've used  {'Uid': '0587848'}, {Uid: 0587848} and single quotes only to uid and only to the number and almost every possible combination i can thin of.The message i'm getting is .... In order to perform a search you need to fill the uid  ..4     .. 227. Translated from greek

@KAEKKAEK those different formatting options that you are saying are as strings -- I am saying that you should have a dict object (please include a sample of a Uid line in your text file, so that we can best provide you with an example)

{'Uid': '0587848'}

I'm not fluent in english neither in python the above example is what every line looks in the text file one under the other

So if you import json you may be able to read the line directly into data using data=json.loads(line) when your line is formatted like this: {"Uid": "0587848"}
Hopefully that helps but it would be best to get a traceback of the error that you are receiving to better find the issue.

I tried using the json.loads method but the response is the same the server doesn't understand that i'm sending the uid .

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

when you read it from file then you have it as string {'Uid': '0587848'} and it sends exactly this string data="{'Uid': '0587848'}" but POST (or rather x-www-form-urlencoded) has to send string "Uid=0587848". When you use dictionary data = { 'Uid': '0587848' } then POST will convert it to string "Uid=0587848"

BTW: function strftime() creates string and you don't have to use str()

maybe keep it in file as Uid=0587848. OR convert string {'Uid': '0587848'} to Uid=0587848 before you send it.
